# Can Spring Cloud Task application can run on embedded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow, embedded-tomcat-8, spring-cloud-task

I have a simple webapp with @EnableTask annotation at main class. My Application is running on embedded tomcat. Is it is possible to run SpringBoot WebApp wrapped with @EnableTask annotation in embedded tomcat. Is yes can i have a simple example for that? Thanks